# mingw ld cannot find -lpthread?

Tags: windows, mingw

I'm trying to cross-compile a C/C++ program for Windows on Linux.

I've gotten to the point where everything compiles properly, except that `x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld` is called with the option `-lpthread`, which doesn't work.

I'm not sure why it's called with that option, because I'm 100% certain that there are no references in the code to threads except through `CreateThread`, which is part of the Windows API. There's no good reason for mingw to try to link in pthreads if I'm not using them, right?

(Fedora 32 but 64-bit, if it helps.)

Comment: If you use a MinGW-w64 GCC that is built with POSIX threads, linking with `-lpthread` should work.

Comment: The issue here is that I don't ask it to link in pthreads. It passes that to the linker for no reason I can see.

Comment: In that case, is it possible you have a mix of toolchains or toolchain versions in your PATH?

Comment: How do I figure that out?

Comment: Ah, it was misconfigured. Will fix that.

Comment: I tried installing mingw libraries from source. It didn't help.

Comment: You should see MinGW as a core C library like glibc or newlib: you don't just compile it seperately, but instead build GCC against it. But normally the MinGW-w64 GCC builds that are part of major Linux distributions should work fine.
You have to make sure you're not accidentally mixing platforms when cross compiling. Specifically in your case: make sure `-lpthread` is not trying to link with a Fedora Linux library (`libpthread.a`) instead of the one for Windows. If needed try to point `LIBRARY_PATH` to MinGW's library path before calling the linker.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand. I'm not asking for -lpthread. The linker is being given it by the compiler without my asking.

Comment: If the MinGW GCC was build with POSIX threads than it's perfectly possible it needs to link with that library. Like I said before, you should make sure it's not taken from the wrong path or linking will fail.

Comment: I'm not trying to build GCC? I'm building something else. I genuinely don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I know you're not trying to build GCC, I was just trying to explain something about the internal workings of GCC, which may decide to link required libraries, like in this case MinGW's libpthread. The thing you need to check is that it's not accidentally linking with some other libpthread on your system.

Comment: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread` is the exact error it gives. I think you may misunderstand: it's not that it found the wrong one, it's that it can't find any and is looking for one.

Comment: Have you checked if you actually have it with `locate libpthread.a` or `find /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -name libpthread.a` (and additionally also maybe the same for `libpthread.dll.a`)? If you find its location you could try to add it to the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable when calling the MinGW-w64 linker.

Comment: Neither of them is found, but what I'm asking is how to keep it from trying to add libpthread to the command line when I don't want it to.

Comment: If your code and none of its dependancies use POSIX threads than it should automatically link with it AFAIK.

Comment: "Should" or "shouldn't"?

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't

Comment: And yet it does, somehow!

Comment: Do you have some minimal code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to teach the GCC compiler driver to drop "-lpthread" if the compiler was configured to include pthread support.

I guess you are trying to do a static build (?) and the libpthread.a is not installed by your toolchain.
See a related bug report @ https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2070571

Comment: That's a bug in MinGW, then. It really shouldn't treat pthreads as the default; it's for Windows, and I don't know about you, but I think "compiling a program that doesn't use pthreads, for Windows, on a Linux box" is a reasonable use-case.

Comment: The mentioned bug has been fixed in Fedora 37. I tried it and did not get the lpthread error anymore. I successfully build a Windows executable on a Linux box.